# Flutter API fetch code throws "index out of range"

Tags: flutter, dart, integration, flutter-web

I wrote a simple webpage widget in Flutter which tries to fetch simple JSON from a public web API but it fails on the very line where it fetches the data. The error message doesn't say anything specific. What am I doing wrong?

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as customhttp;
import '../settings/schemes/color_scheme.dart';

class ContentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ContentPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ContentPage> createState() => _ContentPageState();
}

class _ContentPageState extends State<ContentPage> {
  var _posts = [];

  Future fetchPosts() async {
    try
    {
      String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
      final customhttp.Response response = await customhttp.get(Uri.parse(url));
      final List<dynamic> jsonData = json.decode(response.body) as List;

      setState(() {
        _posts = jsonData;
      });

      print("Got JSON data.");
      print(_posts[0]);
      
    } catch (err) {}
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchPosts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: schemeBackgroundColor,
      body: Container(
        child: Text("JSON DATA:\n ${_posts[0]}"),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

The error I'm getting on line 20:
[image]

Comment: I think the issue is that the list is empty and by trying to fetch the range of the list (in this case 0), you get a returned null value because of it. Try to debug it step by step, first see if the list has value or not.

Comment: I posted a screenshot of step-by-step debugging. The error is thrown at line 20 where I just fetch the data from the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the widget.

You are trying to display the first item of the posts even before getting the data.

```html
Text("JSON DATA:\n ${_posts[0]}"),
```

You should either use [FutureBuilder](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/explore-futurebuilder-in-flutter-9744203b2b8c) or check if the list is emplty or not before displaying the item.

Example:

```html
Text("JSON DATA:\n ${_posts.isEmpty ? 'No Data' : _posts[0]}"),
```

Comment: A followup question - why does the widget build before the `initState` function finishes? Shouldn't `initState` finish before `build` is executed?

Comment: `initState` is a synchronous function. It does not wait for the function to finish before loading the UI

Comment: It doesn't seem to be async according to the documentation nor the source code:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html

Comment: I am saying it's a sync i.e. not async.

Comment: If it's synchroneous then it should finish before `build` is called, no?

Comment: sorry, my bad. What I meant to say is, initstate gets executed only once when the UI loaded. It does not wait for any functions to get executed. So, we have to handle the condition do display the data; if its empty or not .

Comment: OR you can simply use future builder if want to wait for the api to get and display the data

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I might found your problem. When I pasted the code all works well BUT sometimes it doesn't do to the fact that your widget builds before you get the data so hence the error. You might wanna try with this:

```
Text("JSON DATA:\n ${_posts.isEmpty ? 'There is no data' : _posts[0]}")
```

Or you can use a `FutureBuilder()`:

```
 FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchPosts(),
        builder: (context, dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            if (dataSnapshot.error != null) {
              return Center(
                child: Text('An error occured'),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) => Text("JSON DATA:\n ${snapshot.data[i]}"),
                ),
              );
            }
          }
        },
      ),
```

If this doesn't work, let me know so I can find an another solution.

Comment: I've used the `isEmpty` check and it's working. I marked @Suz Zan's answer as the right one as it seemed to me that answer was first. I'm still confused though why the widget  builds before `initState` finishes - or is it only because my `fetchPosts` is async?